# Newbie f# question

Tags: f#, types, tuples

I have a simple function call takes two tuples. Getting compiler error on type:

```
module test

open System.IO
open System

let side (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : float = 
  Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1))

let a = side ( 2s, 3s ) ( 1s, 2s )
```

Error 2 The type 'float' does not match the type 'int16'

Not sure where it goes wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Put 4 spaces before each line of code, it will make it easier for us to read.

Comment: Those are all great answers! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Math.Sqrt expects argument of float, but you pass there int16. F# doesn't perform such implicit conversions

```
let side (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : float = 
    (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)
    |> float
    |> Math.Sqrt
```

or you can pass floats from the very beginning:

```
let side (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : float = Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1))

let a = side ( 2.0, 3.0 ) ( 1.0, 2.0 )
```

Answer (score 6):

As others already pointed out, the F# compiler doesn't automatically insert any conversions between numeric types. This means that if you're writing a function that works with floats, you need to pass it floats as arguments.

The function in your example can work with various types, because `Math.Sqrt` and numeric operators are overloaded. If you write it without any type annotations, you'll get a function working with floats (because `Math.Sqrt` only works with floats):

```
> let side (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = 
    Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));;
val side : float * float -> float * float -> float
```

This can be called only with `floats` as arguments, so you need to call it like Joel suggests. If you want to get a function that takes other type of number as parameter, you'll need to add type annotations and conversion. I would write it like this:

```
> let side (x1:int16,y1) (x2,y2) = 
    let n = (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)
    Math.Sqrt(float(n));;
val side : int16 * int16 -> int16 * int16 -> float
```

We need only a single type annotation (the compiler then figures out that `y1`, `x2`, ... also have to be of type `int16`, because we're multiplying/adding them and that's only allowed on two values of the same type). So, now you can write:

```
side ( 2s, 3s ) ( 1s, 2s )
```

Note that the version by desco is a bit tricky - it adds conversion (using the `float`) function, but it doesn't have type annotation to specify the type of parameters - in this case, the compiler will pick a *default type* which is `int`, so if you use his function, you'll have to call it using `side (2,3) (1,2)`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your function is `float * float -> float * float -> float` but you're passing in `int16` values (that's what the `s` suffix means).

One way to get it to compile would be to do this:

```
let a = side ( 2.0, 3.0 ) ( 1.0, 2.0 )
```